# How does a CPU know if an address in RAM contains an integer, a pre-defined CPU instruction, or any other kind of data?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, machine-code

The reason this gets me confused is that all addresses hold a sequence of 1's and 0's. So how does the CPU differentiate, let's say, `00000100`(integer) from `00000100`(CPU instruction)?

Comment: The CPU has no idea what's in memory. It assumes that the Program Counter points to a valid instruction and attempts to execute that, updates the Program Counter as needed and tries again, rinse and repeat.. The instructions it executes determine how data in memory is handled.

Comment: The [tag:processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, different commands have different values (opcodes). That's how the CPU knows *what* to do.

Finally, the questions remains: What's a command, what's data?

Modern PCs are working with the **von Neumann**-Architecture ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann) where data and opcodes are stored in the same memory space. (There are architectures seperating between these two *data types*, such as the **Harvard architecture**)

Explaining *everything* in Detail would totally be beyond the scope of stackoverflow, most likely the amount of characters per post would not be sufficent.

To answer the question with as few words as possible (Everyone actually working on this level would kill me for the shortcuts in the explanation):

- Data in the memory is stored at certain addresses.
- Each CPU Advice is basically consisting of 3 different addresses (NOT values - just addresses!):

  - Adress about *what to do*
  - Adress about *value*
  - Adress about *an additional value*

So, assuming an addition should be performed, and you have 3 Adresses available in the memory, the application would Store (in case of `5+7`) (I used "verbs" for the instructions)

```
Adress | Stored Value
1      | ADD
2      | 5
3      | 7
```

Finally the CPU receives the instruction `1 2 3`, which then means `ADD 5 7` (These things are order-sensitive! [Command] [v1] [v2])... And now things are getting complicated.

The CPU will move these values (actually not the values, just the adresses of the values) into its *registers* and then processing it. The exact registers to choose depend on datatype, datasize and opcode.

In the case of the command `#1 #2 #3`, the CPU will first read these memory addresses, then knowing that `ADD 5 7` is desired.

Based on the opcode for `ADD` the CPU will know:

- Put Address `#2` into r1
- Put Address `#3` into r2
- Read Memory-Value Stored at the address stored in r1
- Read Memory-Value stored at the address stored in r2
- Add both values
- Write result somewhere in memory
- Store Address of where I put the result into r3
- Store Address stored in r3 into the Memory-Address stored in r1.

**Note** that this is simplified. Actually the CPU needs exact instructions on whether its handling a *value* or *address*. In Assembly this is done by using

- eax (means *value stored in register eax*)
- [eax] (means *value stored in memory at the adress stored in the register eax*)

The CPU cannot perform calculations on values stored in the memory, so it is quite busy moving values From memory to registers and from registers to memory.

i.e. If you have

```
eax = 0x2
```

and in memory

```
0x2 = 110011
```

and the instruction

```
MOV ebx, [eax]
```

this means: *move the value, currently stored at the address, that is currently stored in `eax` into the register `ebx`*. So finally

```
ebx = 110011
```

(This is happening EVERYTIME the CPU does a single calculation!. Memory -> Register -> Memory)

Finally, the demanding application can read its predefined memory address #2,
resulting in address #2568 and then knows, that the outcome of the calculation is stored at adress #2568. Reading that Adress will result in the value `12` (5+7)

This is just a tiny tiny example of whats going on. For a more detailed introduction about this, refer to http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html

One cannot really grasp the amount of data movement and calculations done for a *simple* addition of 2 values. Doing what a CPU does (on paper) would take you several minutes just to calculate "5+7", since there is no "5" and no "7" - Everything is hidden behind an address in memory, pointing to some bits, resulting in different values depending on what the bits at adress 0x1 are instructing...

Answer (score 3):

Short form: The CPU does not know what's stored there, but the instructions tell the CPU how to interpret it.

Let's have a simplified example.

If the CPU is told to add a word (let's say, an 32 bit integer) stored at the location X, it fetches the content of that address and adds it.

If the program counter reaches the same location, the CPU will again fetch this word and execute it as a command.

Answer (score 1):

The CPU (other than security stuff like the NX bit) is blind to whether it's data or code.

The only way data doesn't accidentally get executed as code is by carefully organizing the code to never refer to a location holding data with an instruction meant to operate on code.

When a program is started, the processor starts executing it at a predefined spot. The author of a program written in machine language will have intentionally put the beginning of their program there. From there, that instruction will always end up setting the next location the processor will execute to somewhere this is an instruction. This continues to be the case for all of the instructions that make up the program, unless there is a serious bug in the code.

There are two main ways instructions can set where the processor goes next: jumps/branches, and not explicitly specifying. If the instruction doesn't explicitly specify where to go next, the CPU defaults to the location directly after the current instruction. Contrast that to jumps and branches, which have space to specifically encode the address of the next instruction's address. Jumps always jump to the place specified. Branches check if a condition is true. If it is, the CPU will jump to the encoded location. If the condition is false, it will simply go to the instruction directly after the branch.

Additionally, the a machine language program should never write data to a location that is for instructions, or some other instruction at some future point in the program could try to run what was overwritten with data. Having that happen could cause all sorts of bad things to happen. The data there could have an "opcode" that doesn't match anything the processor knows what to do. Or, the data there could tell the computer to do something completely unintended. Either way, you're in for a bad day. Be glad that your compiler never messes up and accidentally inserts something that does this.

Unfortunately, sometimes the programmer using the compiler messes up, and does something that tells the CPU to write data outside of the area they allocated for data. (A common way this happens in C/C++ is to allocate an array L items long, and use an index >=L when writing data.) Having data written to an area set aside for code is what buffer overflow vulnerabilities are made of. Some program may have a bug that lets a remote machine trick the program into writing data (which the remote machine sent) beyond the end of an area set aside for data, and into an area set aside for code. Then, at some later point, the processor executes that "data" (which, remember, was sent from a remote computer). If the remote computer/attacker was smart, they carefully crafted the "data" that went past the boundary to be valid instructions that do something malicious. (To give them more access, destroy data, send back sensitive data from memory, etc).

Answer (score 0):

this is because an ISA must take into account what a valid set of instructions are and how to encode data: memory address/registers/literals.

see this for more general info on how ISA is designed
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set

Answer (score 0):

In short, the operating system tells it where the next instruction is. In the case of x64 there is a special register called rip (instruction pointer) which holds the address of the next instruction to be executed. It will automatically read the data at this address, decode and execute it, and automatically increment rip by the number of bytes of the instruction.

Generally, the OS can mark regions of memory (pages) as holding executable code or not. If an error or exploit tries to modify executable memory an error should occur, similarly if the CPU finds itself trying to execute non-executable memory it will/should also signal an error and terminate the program. Now you're into the wonderful world of software viruses!